# Laid out or Layed out

Tags: contemporary-english

Layout is a thing.

It originated from sentences including "lay out" ("let us lay this out" "I am about to lay this out" "I like the way you laid out those pieces of metal").

You now have the word "layout" ("here is the layout" "change layout C" or just "Layout", an engine that makes the "layout").

When a layout happens...

Tricky one...

> "We must prepare the shapes for the expansion anime every time we are laid out."

.

> "We must prepare the shapes for the expansion anime every time we are layed out."

Personally I would only use

> "We must prepare the shapes for the expansion anime every time we are layouted."

just as with any of the other 20,000 words in English that started as sentences and became words. You don't suddenly go back to a sentence form when you need another part of speech.  But it's probably not time for that yet.

Consider "layout", historic origins of computing UX vocab in newspapers?, etc.

Comment: This is an extremely common form in modern device engineering.  (Crap like "phones" etc.) If you write the definitive study, it will be used widely.

Comment: It doesn't seem that tricky to me; the first thing Google does when I ask it for "layed out" is give me the results for "laid out", and when I insist I get only results about people asking which spelling is right. If there is a technical jargon where "layed" is correct I haven't come across it.

Comment: OED does include citations for *layed* but the last was 1820-ish with the specific horticultural meaning of *layered.* Before that they peter out around 1620. @JoeBlow **Why** is this "tricky"? Dictionaries would appear to make it easy.

Comment: @AndrewLeach but it's "Layout" (today).  The new single word "Layout" has origins in the sentence "lay out the pieces of metal" but it is now (for ages) an actual word.  I can't believe you don't see the point my man.

Comment: (It's unfortunate that the tag description for "contemporary-English" is remarkably poorly written, on the "Advanced English" site  :O )

Comment: So what's your question here?

Comment: Why are you jumping from a layout being a thing, to being laid out being something that has apparently happened to your 'we'? perhaps it would help if you clarified what particular kind of layout you are talking about. I design layouts for open space and cannot come up with anything I would want to say which would involve it sounding as if someone had felled me with a left hook.

Comment: it's funny that the opening sentence "Layout is a thing" sounds like the current humorous form "is XYZ even a thing?"  Heh.  (I just meant ... Layout is a thing  :) )

Comment: HI @Spagirl - I think it's beautiful that you design layouts in the Capability Brown sense.  And it's incredibly beautiful that you are so isolated from the utter filth and crap of the technological age that you are not familiar with the ordinary meaning today. I want to be you.

Comment: (Come to think, you could easily say "This clos has been layouted, so we can begin the layout on this clos..." or the like. Sure, in your profession layouts happen "in 5 or 17 years" whereas "every frame or two" in the modern world :) )

Answer (score 1):

You're right, "Layout" is a thing. And that thing is a **noun**. There is no verb "to layout" in common English; it might exist in the future, but it doesn't exist in the current English vernacular. That's OK, most English nouns don't also happen to be a verb!

The verb that corresponds to the noun "Layout" is the same phrasal verb it derived from in the first place: "to lay out". And that is conjugated the way you would conjugate any phrasal verb in English.

Which here is "laid out".

Having said that, user Josh in a now-deleted answer pointed out examples of the use of the past participle "layouted" in two books, and a Google search confirms that this usage exists. I am slightly suspicious of the large number of foreign-language results I get from the search, but I'd expect a linguist to determine whether this qualifies as deliberate and shared usage of the word in a technical context or if it is a recurrent mistake, or wordplay.

Given Josh's answer and the examples it contained has disappeared I will add examples myself. A search on Google Books yields the following examples of books that use the word "layouted" :

**IEEE/PES Transmission and Distribution Conference and Exhibition 2002: Asia Pacific: New Wave of T&d Technology from Asia Pacific**, 2002
The following is the legend on a figure in the book:

> (a) Center layouted
> (b) Layouted close to pressure side of main blade
> (c) Layouted close to suction side of main blade

**Graph Drawing: Symposium on Graph Drawing, GD'95; Passau, Germany, September 20-22, 1995. Proceedings**
The word occurs in the following sentences:

> Fisheye views of graphs are pictures of layouted graphs as seen through a fisheye lens.
>
> In a layouted graph, each node *v* is given a position *p(v)* in the plane respective to an orthogonal coordinate system.

**On the Pragmatics of Graphical Modeling**, by **Hauke A. L. Fuhrmann - 2011**
It's about graphs as well:

> The feature that each subgraph can be layouted with a different layout algorithm allows to handle connected and unconnected nodes differently

**Practical PRAM programming**, by **Jörg Keller, Christoph W. Kessler, Jesper Träff**
I'm not giving a quote of this one, it's about graphs again.

**Multimedia: Systems, Interaction and Applications** edited by **Lars Kjelldahl**
This one uses the publishing meaning of "layout" :

> - the final form contains the layouted document in a format directly processable by the presentation process

**Proceedings 1998, 35th Design Automation Conference** of the **Association for Computing Machinery**
Here the word refers to datapaths in microprocessors:

> In previous microprocessors, datapaths were layouted as structured elements.

**Multimodal Film Analysis: How Films Mean** By **John Bateman, Karl-Heinrich Schmidt**

> (3) changing the layouted order of the shots effects neither the temporal container nor the spatial 'container' entailed

None of these are one of the two examples Josh had found. I do notice however that all of these include foreign names, suggesting that they may be written by people who speak English as a second language, and moreover that some of these quotes include what are generally considered English mistakes, which suggests "layouted" could also be a mistake. But in every case it seems to be used deliberately and with a specific technical meaning that the writer seems to expect readers to understand.

I also note all of these results are from the late 90s at the earliest, but this could be an artifact of the Google Books search rankings.

Comment: English is a productive language. No surprise layout has been verbalized, though only is technical contexts. Usage, not linguists, will determine its validity.

Comment: Hi Rozenn (are you a *smooth fiddler*?  :) ) ... yes, in English, it is a feature of contemporary English that you can verbize *absolutely anything* - just literall ***any-thing*** .. sentences, phrases, any word whatsoever.

Comment: @Josh Sure, I didn't mean to say linguists would determine its validity, I meant that linguists are the kind of people with the training and experience (and time to devote to the question) to tell whether the current usage represents people deliberately verbing the word as part of their personal vocabulary, people playing with language or people making a mistake. Even from a descriptivist point of view surely these three concepts have meaning. Having said that, your examples do look like the first one. (it was less obvious in my google search, hence my comment).

Comment: @JoeBlow It's a feature of every language that you can do absolutely everything you want, it doesn't mean other people will understand you or follow you in doing so, which is what is required for those things to be or become part of the language. And while verbing nouns is a productive process in modern English, that doesn't mean every noun has been verbed into standard English. It so happens that "layout" has (though it seems to be rare) but it wasn't obvious from the outset.

Comment: hi Rozenn, "It's a feature of every language that you can do absolutely everything you want".  In English today, at least since Seinfeld, it is *commonplace* that the "anything's a verb" trope thing is used.  (And less in the UK than US.)  This is not the case in other languages.  (Actually, it's an interesting question what other languages today have that same sort of verb-sarcasm - Maybe places Seinfeld played :) )

Comment: @JoeBlow Right, hence "And while verbing nouns is a productive process in modern English..." ;)

Comment: Whether or not verbification should be accepted as having occurred is moot – I can't find authoritative confirmation. But an answer should include research (even negative) rather than give one's opinion / experience / gut feeling.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That's the weird thing though - the answer that disappeared is the one that included actual examples whereas mine doesn't. What's up with that ?